# How use interface property set by another class?

Tags: c#, object

For example I have two classes, but one of those classes have not accees to object. I want create interfaces which method are implement by one of those classes. I have class `Gps` and class have not acces to object like `Point`. But I can implement two variable like `lat` and `lng` and will do something with this. Now I have interfaces

```cs
interface IGps
{
   double Lng{get; set;}
   double Lat{get; set;}
}
```

I want set this property in `class Coords` and use those variable in `class Gps`. This is pseudo "code" for example.

```cs
public class Coords : IGps
{

public double Lng
{
    get
    {
        return Lng;
    }
    set
    {
        Lng = value;
    }
}

public double Lat
{
    get
    {
        return Lat;
    }
    set
    {
        Lat = value;
    }

public Coords()
{
    GeoCoordinate coord = watcher.Position.Location;
    Lng = coord.Lontitude;
    Lat = coord.Latitude;
}

}
```

And i want use this property in class `Gps` but i have no access to class `Coords` and object like`GeoCoordinate`. How can i do this?

Comment: Can you add the other classes in your question?

Comment: i add code but I just don't know if you know what I mean. One class 
says I know how to present it but I can't prepare it. and the second class says that they can do it, but they can't show it

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure I understood. But if you're having issues accessing properties, just make everything `public`, including your interface. I don't if this will work, but at least we can rule it out.

Comment: i have issues to interfaces, but how inject properties with values in class

Comment: Why not pass in the values you require to the constructor of Coords?  `public Coords(GeoCoordinate coord) { ... }`?  As @GuilhermeLofranoCorneto says, more code to show what you are trying to do will help.